# how to pass a state to the gtm.js function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, next.js, google-tag-manager

I'm an intern for a start up and I'm the only front dev. 
I have to code a website in Next.js and my boss asked me to add Google Tag Manager.
I followed the example given by Next in their github example.
Now my boss asked me to add a searchTerm to my gtm.js like so:

```
export const GTM_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID;

export const pageview = (url) => {
  console.log("search ", searchCity);
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: "search",
    searchTerm: searchCity, //this should be dynamically replaced with an actual search query
    page: url,
  });
};
```

I declared the searchCity state in my _app.js :

```
import GoogleTagManager from "../components/GoogleTagManager";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 
  // manage search queries
  const [searchCity, setSearchCity] = useState("");
  return (
    <GoogleTagManager>
      <Component
        {...pageProps}
        searchCity={searchCity}
        setSearchCity={setSearchCity}
      />
    </GoogleTagManager>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

but how do I pass searchCity to the function pageview ? 
The function is in googleTagManager component which is outside the app component so I can not pass searchCity as a props.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would a second parameter named `searchCity` to the `pageview` function:

```
export const pageview = (url, searchCity) => {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: "search",
    searchTerm: searchCity,
    page: url,
  });
};
```

And in your *GoogleTagManager.js* you can pass the parameter like this:

```
router.events.on("routeChangeStart", url => gtm.pageview(url, searchCity));
```

### Edit:

You passed it to the wrong component in your *_app.js*. It should look like this:

```
<GoogleTagManager  searchCity={searchCity} setSearchCity={setSearchCity}>
  <Component
    {...pageProps}  
  />
</GoogleTagManager>
```

);
}

Now you can destructure it in the *GoogleTagManager.js* like this:

```
const GoogleTagManager = ({ children, setSearchCity, searchCity}) => {
```

Comment: I edited my code to show my _app.js I want the value of searchTerm to be the same as searchCity (declared on my _app.js and receiving a value through another component).
How can I pass searchCity to pageview function with the googleTagManager component being outside the _app component ?

Comment: I tried to pass it to the GoogleTagManager but then I don't know how to pass it to the function pageview. If I add gtm.pageview(url, searchCity).
SearchCity will just be the name of the variable, it will not be the state searchCity from my _app.
I tried it anyway but it throws an error (url is not defined) and if I pass just searchCity I got an error (handler is undefined).

Comment: You have to do it like I described in my answer: `url => gtm.pageview(url, searchCity)`. The `on` function of the router receives the url and you pass it into the function together with the `searchCity`.

Comment: Sorry. No more error but searchTerm stays an empty strings or it should get the value of searchCity.

Comment: Have you actually added a value? It will naturally be an empty string if you never change the initial value.

Comment: Yes I did. I console.logged searchCity in my other component and I got a value but if I console.log in my gtm.js i get an empty string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228954/discussion-between-gh05d-and-florie-anstett).

Comment: Sorry I had to disconnect for the week-end but I'd like to contiue this discussion in order to reslove the problem.